# All Editexts be replace by same value after pop a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have a strange issue, I have 2 fragment, in first fragment, I have some custom `EditText`, and a button to replace this by second fragment (`addToBackStack` = true), then, in second fragment, I try to using `popBackStack()` to back to first fragment, the issue occur, all custom `EditText` have same value.

[image: error]

Below is all my code

*FirstFragment*

```
class FirstFragment : BaseFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        btn_next.setOnClickListener {
            val transaction = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contentFrame, SecondFragment(), "")
            commitTransaction(transaction, true, -1)
        }
    }
}
```

*SecondFragment*

```
class SecondFragment : BaseFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        btn_back.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        }
    }
}
```

*fragment_first.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <com.sogia.replacefragmentdemo.CustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <com.sogia.replacefragmentdemo.CustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="next"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

*fragment_second.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="back"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

*CustomView*

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.layout_custom_view, this)
    }
}
```

*layout_custom_view.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="input something"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using your custom EditText (com.sogia.replacefragmentdemo.CustomView) and not the default one?

Comment: @sebasira just for demo this issue, in real code, I using more view

Comment: If you use a default EditText, do you have the same behavior or the problem is gone? If it is gone, then probably the problem is in your custom view. Can you post it if the error is only when using your custom view?

Comment: @sebasira yes, the issue occur  only when I using custom view, but you can see my `CustomView`, it's very clearly and I can not see any problem

Comment: I had a similar issue, have a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45818015/1827254)

Comment: @Eselfar awesome, finally I got it, thank you so much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I find out the root cause and the solution, 
Thanks @abhradeep ghosh, @Eselfar, @MadScientist and another one else who response this post.

Cause:  view IDs should be unique! Otherwise your state will be overwritten by another view with the same ID. In my case I have 2 views with id `@id/edt`, so my states container holds only 1 instance of it - whichever came last during state store process.

Here is my solution, (from [this post](https://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/)),

First, create new class for save sate of view

```
class SavedState(superState: Parcelable) : View.BaseSavedState(superState) {
    var childrenStates: SparseArray<Any>? = null

    override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
        childrenStates?.let {
            out.writeSparseArray(it)
        }
    }
}
```

And in my `CustomView`

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    public override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
        val superState = super.onSaveInstanceState()
        val ss = SavedState(superState)
        ss.childrenStates = SparseArray()
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            getChildAt(i).saveHierarchyState(ss.childrenStates as SparseArray<Parcelable>)
        }
        return ss
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    public override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable) {
        val ss = state as SavedState
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.superState)
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            getChildAt(i).restoreHierarchyState(ss.childrenStates as SparseArray<Parcelable>)
        }
    }

    override fun dispatchSaveInstanceState(container: SparseArray<Parcelable>) {
        dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(container)
    }

    override fun dispatchRestoreInstanceState(container: SparseArray<Parcelable>) {
        dispatchThawSelfOnly(container)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not adding to the back stack, you're replacing, try this to open the second fragment, this will keep the state of FirstFragment intact and in stack

```
btn_next.setOnClickListener {
            val transaction = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.contentFrame, SecondFragment(), "")
            commitTransaction(transaction, true, -1)
        }
```

Also both of your `EditText`s have the same ids `android:id="@+id/edt"` thus the synthesizer function which runs `findViewById` will point to the same object of `EditText`

Comment: I already add fragment to back stack in line 'commitTransaction(transaction, true, -1)', I also think  'kotlinx.android.synthetic' is root cause, but as you see, my code is clearly, I will focus on this point and tell you the result when I come back

Comment: I have answer for this question, that a pity I can not accept your answer because it has no solution, but anw, thank you so much (+1)

Comment: No worries, please do post your answer for knowledge sake. Thank you.

Comment: I did :) please see below

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a different ID to each of your custom views in the layout. Like :

```
com.sogia.replacefragmentdemo.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/custom1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

com.sogia.replacefragmentdemo.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/custom2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Having same id can be a problem as managing state could get messy.
Check this one for an solution:
[Restore fragment with two views having the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818015/restore-fragment-with-two-views-having-the-same-id?noredirect=1&lq=1)